# How to load two .properties into the same resource bundle

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl, resourcebundle

Using jstl `<fmt:message>` tag, how can I configure the container to load messages from two .properties file?

What I need exatclty is a easy way to override the messages in one file. We're building a webapp to be redistributable and other people may need to override the original messages to customize their software.

So, to be easy to upgrade the webapp we need to split the message.properties so that they don't need to merge future updated versions of the original message.properties with their customized version.

Answer (score 2):

The unique solution , actually for me, for use 2 properties file in the same JSP is used the first properties ( internationalization) and the second properties only works when puts the other messasge in the tag of these resource bundle.

For example:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<c:set var="language" value="es_MX" scope="session" />
<fmt:setLocale value="${language}" />
<fmt:setBundle basename="i18n" />
<fmt:bundle basename="app">
    <h1><fmt:message key="application.environment" /></h1>
</fmt:bundle>
<fmt:message key="aplicacion.nombre" />
```

I have two properties files **i18n_es_MX.properties** (aplicacion.nombre) and the other is **app.properties** (application.environment), works fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

Properties extend HashTable. So you can use addAll(). Just load both property files and add the contents of the second one to the first one. Identical keys get overridden.

Comment: In that case it depends on your app container. When does it load the properties? Is there any initialization() method the container invokes from your code? Is your code invoked before the container?

If none of this helps then you must do it during deployment. Deploy your standard file and overwrite entries with the customer specific file entries.

Comment: I really don't known when it load the message.properties file. It should be jstl spec internals